# Combining a single feature from Angular Materials with Bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material

I'm currently working on my Angular 7 web-app using Bootstrap.

I'm not using Bootstrap for its style, most of the time I overwrite it with my personal css.

Now that I'm creating a component I need draggable elments for I took a look a [this Angular Material feature](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview).

**Will there be any issues combining this single feature from Angular Materials with Bootstrap 4?**

One other threads I read that it's not recommended, due to the difference in style etc. But what if I won't use the original styles anyways and if it's only one feature?

Answer (score 0):

There are no compatibility issues between Bootstrap and Angular Material. I've mixed the two together on a few projects without any issues.

You want to install Bootstrap with `npm install -s bootstrap` and then import it into your styles. Importing only the feature you want to use.

For example:

https://github.com/reactgular/bookmarks/blob/015bfdbbbf8530e8e6296f86867ae8130f7191b8/src/app/app.scss#L3